# How to take the first field of each line from a text file and execute it in a while-loop?

Tags: bash, shell

I tried with below script. But, not working for cut the first field of each line and to be executed for "chmod".

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo -e "Usage: $(basename $0) FILE\n"
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -e "$1" ]; then
     echo -e "$1: File doesn't exist.\n"
     exit 1
fi

while read -r line; do
   awk '{print $1}'
   [ -n "$line" ] && chown root "$line" && echo -e "$line Ownership changed"
done < "$1"
```

Comment: Yes, $1 is input file. The input file contains 3 to 4 fields in each line. It should take first field and execute.

Comment: Don't run `awk` repeatedly inside a `while` loop. Pipe the output of `awk` _into_ the `while` loop. (`$1` should be an argument to the `awk` command).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If field separator is space, try this:

```
while read -r line; do
   FILE_TO_CHANGE=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
   [ -n "$line" ] && chown root "$FILE_TO_CHANGE" && echo -e "$line Ownership changed"
done < "$1"
```

`awk` read `$line` and print first token on standard output, the result is saved in `FILE_TO_CHANGE` variable and then it is used to run `chown`.

Another way could be:

```
awk '{print $1}' $1 | while read line; do
   chown root "$line" && echo -e "$line Ownership changed"
done
```

`awk` read your file and print the first field of each line, in this case, `while` loop read `awk` output line by line and run `chown` on field.

Comment: Yes, field separator is space. Both the methods works perfectly. I would say, 2nd is more efficient as awk don't run repeatedly. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could extract the first word on each line with awk and pipe to `xargs`, invoking `chown` only as few times as possible:

```
awk '{print $1}' "$1" | xargs chown root
```